# Using Brand Theme Colors Within Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, theme-branding

we are attempting to style a few attributes of our LWC with colors from the active Branding Theme (not community themes). We're debugging our way through this. Also not finding much in the way of documentation on the subject.

Any experience in this regard would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the design tokens for SLDS, listed [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/), but [modified for LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_design_tokens).

For example, to use the "active" brand color (the color for an active item), use:

```
.my-selector {
    color: var(--lwc-brandAccessibleActive)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the second doc was exactly what we needed.The note on referencing the variables at runtime was important to know.